# Create Output using PHP for Specific Category of a Post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories, posts

I'm new to PHP coding and am trying to make this section output post from a specific category, say "Events". I've tried looking at different examples but couldn't find anything that seemed to fit the coding in this PHP template. I would think it is a simple addition that I am missing.

Here is the current code I have:

```
<?php $args=array( 'posts_per_page'=> 3, 'post_type' => 'post'); $myposts = get_posts( $args ); foreach ($myposts as $post) { ?>

                  <?php $content=$post->post_content; ?>
                  <?php $contnt=substr($content, 0, 150);?>
                  <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
                  <p>
                  <div style="float: left; margin-right: 30px;margin-bottom:10px; width:113px">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                  </div>
                  </p>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <img src="<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/noimageavailable2.jpg" style="float: left; margin-right: 30px;margin-bottom:10px; width:113px">
                  <?php } ?>
                  <h4> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a></h4>
                  <p>
                    <?php the_excerpt();?>
                    .....</p>
                  <hr class="line-dots clearbreak">
                  <?php } ?>
```

Any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to appart your logic from your template. This will help you to understand better your code.

Now, php has a template syntax. I could translate your code like this:

```
<?php
$args=array( 'posts_per_page'=> 3, 'post_type' => 'post');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($myposts as $post): ?>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
    <p>
        <div style="float: left; margin-right: 30px;margin-bottom:10px; width:113px">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
    </p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <img src="<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/noimageavailable2.jpg" style="float: left; margin-right: 30px;margin-bottom:10px; width:113px">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a></h4>
    <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
    <hr class="line-dots clearbreak">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now it looks much easier to understand, doesn't it?